# Проблемы при копировании массива в С++

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Есть функция которая возвращает массив:

```
byte *array(const ByteArray &src, int begin, const unsigned& countElement) {
std::vector<unsigned char> arr(countElement);
try {

    for (int i = 0; i < countElement; i++, begin++) {
        arr[i] = src[begin];
    }

}
catch (std::exception e) {
    std::cout << "error";
}

return &arr[0]
}
```

Однако когда я итерирую по результату я получаю только первое значение, дальше идет полная дичь, хотя дебаггер показывает на рутурне ожидаемый результат, но после:

```
byte *val1 = array(msg, startData, 4);

    for (int i = 0x0; i < 0x4;i++) {
        std::cout << val1[i] << std::endl;
    }
```

ожидаемым оказывается только элемент с индексом один, дальше идут одинаковые байты со значением 221, хотя я такие значения не посылал.

ПОЧЕМУ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта функция возвращает не массив, а невалидный указатель на первый элемент, хранившийся в векторе `arr`, который выходит из области видимости. Возвращайте сам вектор.

Еще можно добавить, что обработка исключений сделана неправильно, в блоке `for` никаких исключений быть не может, а исключение потенциально бросаемое из конструктора вектора не перехватывается.

Comment: А разве вектор не хранит элементы подряд? Есть функция даже data() который возвращает указатель на первый элемент и она мне выдавала туже дичь. Я попробую с вектором,но как вектор переделать в массив?

Comment: @Amos Хранит, но этот вектор уничтожается при выходе из функции.

Comment: Тогда на что ссылается мой массив?

Comment: @Amos Я же написал, у вас из функции возвращается невалидный указатель. Его разыменование является неопределенным поведением.

Comment: Верните не указатель а допустим сам вектор и тогда все будет ок или ещё как вариант передайте пустой вектор по ссылке в аргументе и не возвращайте тогда ничего из функции

Comment: Да, все верно:\